# Defining Induced map of homology groups of torus

Tags: algebraic-topology

In this question [1]: [Induced map of homology groups of torus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1179449/induced-map-of-homology-groups-of-torus) 
I couldn't understand the induced map on $H_1(X)$,  $f_∗:H_1(X)→H_1(X)$  look like, how we define this map ?

Comment: The same way you define induced maps on homology for any map of spaces? You can find the definition in any algebraic topology book.

Comment: @Mike this is general problem of me. I could not define the induce maps on homology.  I read Hatcher Alg.Topology book but I haven't seen anything about it.

Comment: Have you tried the index at the back of the book?

Comment: @Lee soryy for delayed reply,  I have looked but I didin't see anything about calculation about induced map. Do you think I overlook something?

Comment: Did you look up the word "induced" in the index?